# Keep global reference to assetmanager

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am opening a file to read in my native environment using a assetmanager from Java. I wish to open this file only once on init and then use the functions defined within the file multiple times. I need to keep the assetmanager global for this purpose. I currently have the following in C++:

```
extern "C" {

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_torch_torchdemo_TorchDemo_callTorch( JNIEnv* env,
                                            jobject thiz,
                                            jobject assetManager) {
// get native asset manager
if(globalManager == NULL){
jobject globalManager = env->NewGlobalRef(assetManager)
AAssetManager* manager = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, globalManager);
}
```

However, this complains that globalManager is not defined. Which makes sense because at init, it isn't. I cannot find any references on how to get around this. Most of the global reference problems are about keeping a reference to an object. However, I need to keep a reference to AAssetManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, this complains that globalManager is not defined.

Of course it does. It isn't defined.

> Which makes sense because at init, it isn't. I cannot find any references on how to get around this.

Err, did you consider *defining* it?

Clearly what you need is a 'static jobject globalManager' declare at global scope, not a localvariable declared in the block after you first try to use it.

Comment: Thanks. I did consider it but it gave me an error that said no matching function call to NewGlobalRef so I thought it was incorrect to do it like that. Obviously since you have suggested that, my error must lie elsewhere. Thank you.